# Getting TypeError: this.props.users.items is undefined on ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an application in ReactJs based on GitHub Api.
I get this error `this.props.users.items is undefined`.  This is my Api link https://api.github.com/search/users?q=A  and I see it so that there is an object and in it an array of items. How to refer to this api to get a list of users?

This is UserList component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import User from "./ItemUser"

class UsersList extends Component {

  get users() {
    return this.props.users.items.map(user => <User key={user.id} user={user}/>);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.users }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default UsersList;
```

Comment: You need to do `.then(json => this.setState({ users: json.data })`

Comment: You aren't fetching users before passing them.

Comment: @Arup It did not help, the same mistake :<

Comment: @Elder Ok one more guard is `{ this.users.length > 0 &&  this.users  }`.. because initially they are empty.

Comment: Ok, its work i change 

 get users() {
    return  this.props.users ? this.props.users.items.map(user => <User key={user.id} user={user}/>) : null;
  }
 and in state i set users: null :) Thanks

Comment: do `this.props.users.length > 0` and keep empty array in state as you had before.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are updating state `asynchronously` the initial state ie: {} an empty Object is passed as props.

Set initial state as null
and in render check whether it is updated or not and return the element

```
....
this.state = {
  users: null
};
....
render() {
   ....
     {this.state.users ? (
         <UsersList users={this.state.users}/>
     ) : (
         null
         // or a loading placeholder
     )}
   ....
}
```

Comment: Why `null`? an **empty** array is totally fine.